# Create an instance of an abstract class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to use it in my Android project. I have this code:

```
public var oneTouchTimer: CountDownTimer = CountDownTimer(500, 100) {
    override fun onTick(l: Long) {

    }

    override fun onFinish() {

    }
}
```

And it's throwing the error:

```
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
```

Basically I'm trying to create an instance of CountDownTimer and cannot figure out how to convert it to Kotlin.

Here is the code in Java:

```
CountDownTimer oneTouchTimer = new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
var variableName = object: CountDownTimer(...){
    ...
}
```

These are called "object expressions" in Kotlin. The docs are available here: [Object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

Comment: For those curious, these are called "object expressions" in Kotlin. The docs are available here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Comment: Is it possible to assign a `simpleName` value to an object expression?

Comment: How can you assign the object **variableName** to null at some point later in the code?

Comment: Look like you should use nullable, for example var variableName: CountDownTimer? = object: ...

Answer (score -2):

Just makes sure you have compatible data types

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. OP asked about syntax to instantiate abstract classes.